# Column and Row is not Correct coded, Try to get the Text Container in right place

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have started Rebuilding my Layout on the website.

The area I want for the moment is:

1x Topnav
1x Sidenav
1x main Area
1x Footer
1x float Link area

I want the sidenav to go over the topnav, because the sidenav will be a nav that you can close and open. link this:

[Sidenav - Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFIF7.png)

[Sidenav - After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqKmp.png)

And I want the Topnav Links to start at the point where the sidenav ends when it's open.
Something like this:

[Sidenav Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xAUJ.png)

[Sidenav Close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6f6u.png)

And I want a footer but will be The Next step after this problem i have.

and I want the floating link menu at the right bottom corner.
Like this:

[Floating link menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM6Yl.png)

Ok, let's come to the Question I need help with. I think I have made the code wrong on my page. I want to get the Content area where the light blue area is, anyone that can help me fix the code?

I have marked the area with a Red rectangle where I want the content to be. And the light blue is the sidebar area, and I don't get it why the sidebar area is there :/

[Content area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se7Pe.png)

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    background-color: #cc00ff;
}

.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.padding-0{
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
.col-md-4 {
    width: 280px;
}

nav{
  display: flex ;
  background: #000; 
}

#sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100vh;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background: #0f0c29;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #24243e, #302b63, #0f0c29); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

/* Float LINK Menu */
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1000
}

.wrapper a:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: green
}

.wrapper a:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 170)
}
.wrapper a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: black
}
.wrapper a:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: red
}

.wrapper a:nth-child(4) {
    animation: 0.7s ease-out 0s 1 FadeIn;
    transition: all 0.3s
}

.wrapper a:hover:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow
    
}
.wrapper a:hover:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: yellow
}
.wrapper a:hover:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: yellow
}
.wrapper a:hover:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: yellow
}


@keyframes FadeIn {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

.hide {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 2s
}

.social {}

.wrapper a {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 2px
}
/* ---------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------- */



@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
.nav-link {
    transition: none
   }
}

.nav-link:focus, .nav-link:hover {
    color: #0a58ca
}
.nav-link {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: .25rem
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: .5rem
}
.navbar > .container-xl {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: .3125rem;
    padding-bottom: .3125rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap
}
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0
}
.navbar-text {
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom: .5rem
}
.navbar-collapse {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!-- My CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">


    <title>JGTElite - World of Matrix</title>

</head>


<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 padding-0">                
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" id="sidebar">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> News</a>       
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i> News</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> Tutorials</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Contact</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Sign Up</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Login</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Link 1</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Link 2</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Link 3</a>
                        <hr>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i> Link 4</a>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-10 padding-0" style="background-color: blue;">
            
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark">
                    <div class="container-xl">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                                <a class="nav-link active border-bottom" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Home</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">News</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Tutorials</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Contact</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Sign Up</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Login</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Link 1</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Link 2</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="index2.html">Link 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: darkgreen;">.</div>

                
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: rgb(170, 6, 6);">
                    
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                        Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, 
                        sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. 
                        Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. 
                        Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, 
                    </p>
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                        Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, 
                        sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. 
                        Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. 
                        Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, 
                    </p>
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                        Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, 
                        sit amet adipiscing sem neque sit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem neque

                    </p>
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. 
                    </p>
                
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: darkgray;">
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                        Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, 
                        sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. 
                        Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. 
                        Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, 
                    </p>
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                        Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, 
                        sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. 
                        Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. 
                        Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, 
                    </p>
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. 
                        Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, 
                        sit amet adipiscing sem neque sit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem nequesit amet adipiscing sem neque
                        
                    </p>
                    <h1>
                        Vivamus elementum semper nisi
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
                        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
                        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, 
                        vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. 
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, 
                        enim. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            </div>
          


        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ------- -->
        <div class="Floating-button">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <a class="social" href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
                <a class="social" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a class="social" href="#"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a>
                <a class="social" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                <a class="close-button" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- ------- -->


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Okey hope I write the text right this time. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Move the div that has "SSSS.." under the "sidebar"